# Optimizing flexbox CSS code for different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The code snippet below technically achieves the goal of having a footer that has layout for wide and small screens as seen in the images below.

My question, am I using flex box correctly? Is there a more optimal way to achieve the desired result as seen in the images? I ask as my css feels verbose and I'd like to learn if there's a better way.

**WIDE Screen:**

[image: WIDE]

**SMALL Screen:**

[image: SMALL]

```css
.appFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}
.appFooter ul.navigation {
  margin: 0 0 48px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.appFooter > * {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .appFooter {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .appFooter ul.navigation {
    margin: 0;
    order: 2;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .appFooter ul.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .appFooter ul.navigation li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .appFooter .copyright {
    order: 1;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .appFooter > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="appFooter">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Terms of Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="copyright">
    <span>&copy; 2018 Site</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would say there's room for simplification in your code (both the CSS and HTML).

This should be all you need:

```css
.appFooter {
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .appFooter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .navigation {
    flex-direction: row;
    order: 1;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navigation a + a {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="appFooter">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="/">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="/">Terms of Service</a>
    <a href="/">Privacy Policy</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="copyright">&copy; 2018 Site</div>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1sw59n4v/

Answer (score 1):

For your desktop view, you don't need to worry about all the **[`order`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/)** and **[`text-align`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)** declarations, as you can achieve the same result with **[`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)**. Keep in mind that you'll still want to allow the elements to span a single line, you'll additionally need to remove the `flex` on the children with **[`flex: inherit`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)**.

Also keep in mind that with your example, you have things like **[`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)** in the media query. These don't need to be re-declared in the media query, as the rules are inherited :)

Here's an example using `flex-direction: row-reverse` that cuts out the re-declarations:

```css
.appFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.appFooter ul.navigation {
  margin: 0 0 48px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.appFooter > * {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .appFooter {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  
  .appFooter > * {
    flex: inherit;
  }
  
  .appFooter ul.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .appFooter ul.navigation li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="appFooter">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Terms of Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="copyright">
    <span>&copy; 2018 Site</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

This cuts out more than half of your media query declarations, giving the exact same result.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize/shorten that code quite a bit, and at the same time increase its render flexibility.

By simply remove all elements but the actual links `a` and the copyright `span`, you easily control both their stacking/render order and alignment.

Initially set:

- `flex-direction: column`, vertical direction
- `margin: 48px 0 0 0`, top margin for copyright

With the media query:

- `flex-direction: row`, switch to horizontal direction
- `order: -1`, position the copyright first in order, enable it to align left
- `margin: 0 auto 0 0`, reset top and push the links to the right by make its right margin "auto"

Stack snippet

```css
.appFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.appFooter span {
  margin: 48px 0 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .appFooter {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .appFooter span {
    order: -1;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  }
  .appFooter a + a {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="appFooter">
  <a href="/">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="/">Terms of Service</a>
  <a href="/">Privacy Policy</a>
  <span>&copy; 2018 Site</span>
</footer>
```

---

If you still want to wrap the links, just add its selector to the `.appFooter {...}` rule.

Stack snippet

```css
.appFooter, .appFooter nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.appFooter span {
  margin: 48px 0 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .appFooter, .appFooter nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .appFooter span {
    order: -1;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  }
  .appFooter a + a {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="appFooter">
  <nav>
    <a href="/">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="/">Terms of Service</a>
    <a href="/">Privacy Policy</a>
  </nav>
  <span>&copy; 2018 Site</span>
</footer>
```